# Loading a gallery of external images with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a gallery of images pulled in via a twitter image hosting service, and I want to show a loading graphic before they are displayed, but the logic seems to be failing me. I'm trying to do it the following way:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="holder loading">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="holder loading">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Where there "loading" class has an animated spinner set as it's background image.

JQuery:

```
$('.holder').each(function(){
    var imgsrc = 'http://example.com/imgsrc';
var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent('.holder').removeClass('loading');
        $(this).parent().append(this);
        $(this).fadeIn();
})
.error(function () {
}).attr('src', imgsrc);
 });
```

Which isn't working - I'm not sure that the logic is correct and how to access the "holder" from inside the img.load nested function.  What would be the best way to build this gallery so that the images display only after they've been loaded?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you are not quoting the URL here:

```
var imgsrc = http://example.com/imgsrc;
```

should be:

```
var imgsrc = 'http://example.com/imgsrc';
```

Try this:

```
$('.holder').each(function(){
    var imgsrc = 'http://example.com/imgsrc';
    var $img = $('<img />', {src: imgsrc});
    $($img).load(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent('.holder').removeClass('loading');
        $(this).parent().append(this);
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

I think the problem was that the load event was bound to an image *without* any `src` attribute (I could be wrong, do let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Tried this, still no go - the images are being called but the loading class is not being removed, and images not being displayed in the holder... my brain is confused!

Answer (score 0):

So after much confusion and searching, I figured it out - to access the holder from within the nested function, I had to create a holder for it:

```
$('.holder').each(function(){
   var holder = $(this);
   var imgsrc = 'http://example.com/imgsrc';
   var $img = $('<img />', {src: imgsrc});
   $($img).load(function () {
       $(this).hide();
       holder.removeClass('loading');
       holder.append(this);
       $(this).fadeIn();
   });
});
```

Comment: "this" in the inner function will not refer to the same thing as "this" in the outer function.  A common way around this is to assign `var that = this;` in the outer function then use 'that' instead of 'this' in the inner function.